# Data Import from Oracle to Sql server on monthly basis using DTS

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to import data from an Oracle 10g database table into SQL server 2005 database.
I used Import/export wizard to manually import the table data and it worked fine. 
But,now I need help to automate it on monthly basis (from production environment) by using a DTS package.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can create DTS package and schedule it using SQL Server Agent (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216438(v=sql.80).aspx)